# Cannot resolve ParseFacebookUtils Calss while integrating Facebook signup/login with Parse

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

i have with facebook login using parse database include parse lib and facebook sdk lib but ParseFacebookUtils class can't resolve symbol execption.

```
 dependencies {
        compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+'
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.1'
        compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar')
        compile fileTree(include: 'ParseFacebookUtilsV4-*.jar', dir: 'libs')
        compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.0.0'
        compile 'com.parse:parseui-widget-android:0.0.1'
        compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
        compile 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.4'

    }
```

Comment: it seems you have too many dependencies for the same library, i.e   compile files('libs/Parse-1.9.1.jar') this is not needed if you have this  compile 'com.parse:parse-android:1.+', and you have added facebook dependency twice, fix this things and try to clean and rebuilt

Comment: sorry to be late comment, thanks for regarding me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using android studio and following "How to add Facebook login to your Android App" the tutorial don't copy and paste the text "ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(this);" instead write yourself